# How to relate data by index in list (or csv file)?

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm loading three files.csv. I converted these files into three lists to make them easier to manipulate and obtain certain data to compute and make operations. The problem is that I need to correlate these three files.csv or lists to get the appropriate data:

I want to calculate the number of people (men or women) by age range that rated movies of that genre.

**file names:**

- **movies.csv** : contains (separated by comma) an identifier of the movie, the title of the movie and its genres separated by the character |.

  > Movie_ID, Movie_Title, Gender1 | Gender2 | ...
  >
  > > 1,Toy Story (1995),Animation|Children’s|Comedy
- **rate.csv** : contains a rate that a user made on a
  particular movie. Just commas are used to separate the fields.

  > User_ID, Movie_ID, Rating
  >
  > > 1,1193,5
- **users.csv** : contains (separated by comma) an identifier of
  user, gender ("M": male, "F": female) and age range (1: under 18, 18:
  between 18-24, 25: between 25-34, 35: between 35-44, 45: between 45-49, 50: between 50-55, 56: more than 55).

  > User_ID, Gender, Age_Range
  >
  > > 1,F,1

**My code:**

```py
def opFiles_to_list(filename):
  '''open a csv and convert it to list'''
  with open(filename, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ",", lineterminator = '\n')
    new_list = list(reader)
  return new_list

def statistics(genre_ppl, genre_movie):
  rango = 0
  id_movie = 0
  id_user = 0
  nnew_list = []
  x = []

  if genre_ppl == 'F':
    rating_list = opFiles_to_list(rating)
    users_list = opFiles_to_list(user)
    movies_list = opFiles_to_list(movies)

    for i in movies_list:
      id_movies += 1

      for j in i:
        if j == genre_movies:
        #here I'm getting just the movies delimited by , like Comedy,
        #but not the ones that have this | separator: Comedy|Drama
          nnew_list.append(movies_list[id_movies - 1])
```

**Expected output:**

```py
Input gender: M
Input movie genre: Comedy
Minor Rank 18: 2184
Rank 18-24: 11239
Rank 25-34: 22597
Rank 35-44: 11489
Rank 45-49: 5548
Rank 50-55: 4184
Major rank 56: 2066
```

**Current output:**

If I print the `nnew_list` I will **only** get movies delimited by `,` and, e.g., of the Comedy genre, not including the ones that are delimied by `|`, e.g. Comedy|Drama.

Comment: ***"I want to calculate the number of people (men or women)"***: Why do you have `if genre_ppl == 'F':` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the gender problem: str.split and separate by "|".

The movie and user ids are unique and also used in rate to link with the other two csv, I use a dictionary with the id as the key to store the data of movies.csv and users.csv is a good idea to facilitate searches.

Something like this:

```py
import csv

movies = {}
with open("movies.csv", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",", lineterminator='\n')
    for id_, title, gender  in reader:
        movies[id_] = {"title": title, "gender": set(gender.split("|"))}

users = {}
with open("users.csv", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",", lineterminator='\n')
    for id_, gender, age_range  in reader:
        users[id_] = {"age_range": age_range, "gender": gender}


genrep = input("Input genre: ")
genre_mov = input("Input movie: ")    
count = {"1": 0, "18": 0, "25": 0, "35": 0, "45": 0, "50": 0, "56": 0}

with open("rate.csv", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",", lineterminator='\n')
    for user_id, movie_id, _  in reader:
        user = users.get(user_id)
        movie = movies.get(movie_id)
        if user["gender"] == genrep and genre_mov in movie["gender"]:
            count[user["age_range"]] += 1

print(f"Minor Rank 18: {count['1']}",
      f"Rank 18-24: {count['18']}",
      f"Rank 25-34: {count['25']}",
      f"Rank 35-44: {count['35']}",
      f"Rank 45-49: {count['45']}",
      f"Rank 50-55: {count['50']}",
      f"Mayor rank 56: {count['56']}",
      sep="\n"
      )
```

Every id present in rate.csv is present in the other two dictionaries, although otherwise it would be sufficient to verify that the dict.get methods do not return None.